# UITableView and UITextField borderColor issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm new to Swift, learning more by doing. Unable to pinpoint my error.
Whether I'm coding wrong or implementing it wrong.

I'm trying to implement a theming feature with the help of [Chameleon](https://github.com/viccalexander/Chameleon) framework.
I've been able to change the color of a few UI elements such as `UISegmentedControl` and `UIButton`, but I've not been able to change the `borderColor` of a `UITextField` and the `borderColor` as well as separatorColor of a `UITableView`. The color changes for `UITextField` and `UITableView` are done on the respective component's layers.
Could the layer be my problem?

Preview:

[image: Preview]

1. 1st screen: `ViewController`
2. 2nd screen: `ColorTableViewController`

My code:
**//  ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import ChameleonFramework
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    var themeColor = UIColor.black {
        didSet{
            if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "themeColor") != nil) {
                themeColor = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "themeColor") as! UIColor
            }
            else{
                themeColor = UIColor.black
            }
        }
    }
    var themeContrastColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet{
            if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "contrastThemeColor") != nil) {
                themeContrastColor = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "contrastThemeColor") as! UIColor
            }
            else{
                themeContrastColor = UIColor.white
            }
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        styleUI()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func styleUI(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.segmentedControl.tintColor = self.themeColor

            self.tableView.tintColor = self.themeColor
            self.tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            self.tableView.layer.borderColor = self.themeColor.cgColor
            self.tableView.separatorColor = self.themeColor

            self.textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            self.textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
            self.textField.layer.borderColor = self.themeColor.cgColor
            self.textField.tintColor = self.themeColor

            self.button.backgroundColor = self.themeColor
            self.button.tintColor = self.themeContrastColor
        }


    }


}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) 
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Row: \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

}
```

**//  ColorTableViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import ChameleonFramework
import CDAlertView

class ColorTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var chameleonColorNames = ["Maroon (dark)","Maroon (light)",
                               "Red (dark)","Red (light)",
                               "Watermelon (dark)","Watermelon (light)",
                               "Orange (dark)","Orange (light)",
                               "Yellow (dark)","Yellow (light)",
                               "Lime (dark)","Lime (light)",
                               "Green (dark)","Green (light)",
                               "Mint (dark)","Mint (light)",
                               "Forest Green(dark)","Forest Green(light)",
                               "Teal (dark)","Teal (light)",
                               "Navy Blue(dark)","Navy Blue(light)",
                               "Blue (dark)","Blue (light)",
                               "Sky Blue(dark)","Sky Blue(light)",
                               "Powder Blue(dark)","Powder Blue (light)",
                               "Plum (dark)","Plum (light)",
                               "Purple (dark)","Purple (light)",
                               "Magenta (dark)","Magenta (light)",
                               "Pink (dark)","Pink (light)",
                               "Brown (dark)","Brown (light)",
                               "Coffee (dark)","Coffee (light)",
                               "Sand (dark)","Sand (light)",
                               "Black",
                               "Gray (dark)","Gray (light)",
                               "White (dark)","White (light)"]
    var chameleonColors = [UIColor.flatMaroonDark,UIColor.flatMaroon,
                           UIColor.flatRedDark,UIColor.flatRed,
                           UIColor.flatWatermelonDark,UIColor.flatWatermelon,
                           UIColor.flatOrangeDark,UIColor.flatOrange,
                           UIColor.flatYellowDark,UIColor.flatYellow,
                           UIColor.flatLimeDark, UIColor.flatLime,
                           UIColor.flatGreenDark,UIColor.flatGreen,
                           UIColor.flatMintDark,UIColor.flatMint,
                           UIColor.flatForestGreenDark,UIColor.flatForestGreen,
                           UIColor.flatTealDark,UIColor.flatTeal,
                           UIColor.flatNavyBlueDark,UIColor.flatNavyBlue,
                           UIColor.flatBlueDark,UIColor.flatBlue,
                           UIColor.flatSkyBlueDark,UIColor.flatSkyBlue,
                           UIColor.flatPowderBlueDark,UIColor.flatPowderBlue,
                           UIColor.flatPlumDark,UIColor.flatPlum,
                           UIColor.flatPurpleDark,UIColor.flatPurple,
                           UIColor.flatMagentaDark,UIColor.flatMagenta,
                           UIColor.flatPinkDark,UIColor.flatPink,
                           UIColor.flatBrownDark,UIColor.flatBrown,
                           UIColor.flatCoffeeDark,UIColor.flatCoffee,
                           UIColor.flatSandDark,UIColor.flatSand,
                           UIColor.flatBlack,
                           UIColor.flatGrayDark,UIColor.flatGray,
                           UIColor.flatWhiteDark,UIColor.flatWhite]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return chameleonColorNames.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "colorCell", for: indexPath) as! ColorTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.colorNameLabel.text = chameleonColorNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.colorView.backgroundColor = chameleonColors[indexPath.row]


        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 43.5
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("\(chameleonColorNames [indexPath.row])")

        let selectedThemeColor = chameleonColors[indexPath.row]
        let alert = CDAlertView(title: "Theme", message: " Apply \(chameleonColorNames[indexPath.row]) theme?" , type: .notification)
        alert.circleFillColor = selectedThemeColor

        alert.hideAnimations = { (center, transform, alpha) in
            transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.3, y: 0.3)
            alpha = 0
        }

        let doneAction = CDAlertViewAction(title: "Yes", handler: { action in
            self.applyTheme(selectedColor: selectedThemeColor)
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        })
        let noAction = CDAlertViewAction(title: "No")
        alert.add(action: doneAction)
        alert.add(action: noAction)
        alert.show()
    }

    func applyTheme(selectedColor: UIColor) {
        Chameleon.setGlobalThemeUsingPrimaryColor(selectedColor, with: .contrast)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = selectedColor
        let contrastingColor = UIColor(contrastingBlackOrWhiteColorOn:selectedColor, isFlat: true)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : contrastingColor]
        saveThemeColors(thmColor: selectedColor, contrastColor: contrastingColor)

    }
    func saveThemeColors(thmColor: UIColor,contrastColor: UIColor)  {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(thmColor, forKey: "themeColor") 
        UserDefaults.standard.set(contrastColor, forKey: "contrastThemeColor")
    }
}
extension UserDefaults {
    func set(_ color: UIColor, forKey key: String) {
        set(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color), forKey: key)
    }
    func color(forKey key: String) -> UIColor? {
        guard let data = data(forKey: key) else { return nil }
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? UIColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didSet is called immediately after the new value is stored to your variable. In your situation your variable's didSet is not calling. Try to update your theme color and themeContrastColor on viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear blocks.

After that you should recall your styleUI() method again in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

```
var themeColor = UIColor.black
var themeContrastColor = UIColor.white

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let themeColorData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "themeColor")
    let contrastColorData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "contrastThemeColor")

    themeColor = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: themeColorData as! Data) as? UIColor)!
    themeContrastColor = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: contrastColorData as! Data) as? UIColor)!

    styleUI()
}
```

or you can use delegate protocol to inform your viewController instead of using viewDidAppear.

Comment: Thank you @U. Benlice , appreciate your help . Your solution worked, though I had to tweak it a bit. Updating the solution for others who encounter a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `var themeColor = UIColor.black`, try just using:

```
var themeColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Dramond , appreciate your help.